# QuillJS preview is not as editor view- formatting issue

Tags: quill, react-quill

i am using react quill editor and the editor is working fine. but when i display the html content its not in the format shown in editor view. in console i can see that ql-indent class was applied to tag but its not working outside editor. i tried applying quill core.css styles but still no use.

It's difficult to find a guide on displaying quill-editor html content outside the editor.
so please help me in handing ql-xxxx classes outside editor.

[image]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

i fixed it by adding ql-editor class to the preview div tag.

```
<div className="ql-editor" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: htmlContent}} />
```

Comment: Adding the class name also resolved an issue where it automatically added double lines on an `Enter`